# MySQL Unique Data

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all I have a column called tags with between from 1 to unlimited tags in it which would be separated by semicolons and also it has over 100 rows

I need to build a menu tree using the rows and columns so I have to get the individual unique values, can anyone help me accomplish this as I am unsure of how to do it.

```
+--+---------------------+
|id|tags                 |
+--+---------------------+
|1 |comedy;drama;tv      |
|2 |comedy;horror;movie  |
|3 |horror;tv;pictures   |
|4 |sitcom               |
|5 |drama;book           |
+--+---------------------+
```

Result should be

```
$array = array("comedy", "horror", "movie", "pictures", "drama", "tv", "sitcom", "book");
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're sure that there's never more than 10 tags?

Comment: How the desired output would look like?

Comment: Updated as per request

Answer (score 0):

Do your query then do an explode on each row from the query:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

This will return an array which you can then loop through and do what you want with. Something like this:

```
$ExplodedResult = explode(";",$Row);


array()
(
    [0] => "comedy"
    [1] => "drama"
    [2] => "tv"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be useful to you.

http://www.tero.co.uk/scripts/mysql.php

Split the strings using delimiter and then get the distinct ones out of it.
Another option:

$explodedResult[] = explode(";",$row);

Get the all the tags from each row into a single array and then use 'array_unique' https://www.php.net/function.array-unique

Answer (score 0):

The below does the thing.. check it out..

```
$query = "select tags from tags";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$exploded_tags=array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$unexploded_tags=$rows['tags'];
$exploded_tags=array_merge($exploded_tags,explode(';',$unexploded_tags));
}
$exploded_tags=array_unique($exploded_tags);
print_r($exploded_tags)
```